# How to properly apply an image sequence texture to an imported alembic file?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, import, uv-image-editor, alembic

I've imported an alembic file of a fluid simulation from Houdini and am trying to apply a sequence of image textures (displacement maps that I have also exported from Houdini for the ocean spectrum, which include the UV attribute), but in the viewport and the render, it only displays the first image of the sequence and on the other frames it displays a block color. I have an incling that the issue is that the alembic file is only UV-unwrapped in the first frame and that the map does not apply for the next frames, especially since the vertex count of the alembic changes per frame, but I'm not sure how to fix this. As far as I know multiple UV maps can not be imported into Blender from Houdini. Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, make sure you're creating a UV attribute and keeping 'deform input geometry' deselected in the ocean evaluate node in Houdini, then add an attribute promote node and convert your 'uv' attribute from a point to a vertex attribute, then add the ROP alembic output and export as normal. Upon import into Blender, the image sequence texture should work as expected and the UV mappings will be correct!